# Phoenix framework: how to generate an Ecto model with columns of type list with a phoenix.gen task?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I want to generate an [Ecto model](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/ecto-models) with columns of type [`list`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html), like this:

```
...
users: [
  %{
    id: 1
  },
  %{
    id: 2
  }
]
...
```

Using a [`phoenix.gen`](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/mix-tasks) task. Could you help me out?

Comment: It heavily depends on DB backend used. For PostgreSQL, simply use `json` field type. Here is [more info on embedding structures into](https://medium.com/@alanpeabody/embedding-elixir-structs-in-ecto-models-8f4fcbc06baa#.wbm40aqnt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you actually want is a has_many relationship. Is that correct?

If so, you may want to check out [this blog post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/) that explains how Phoenix does that.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I was wondering if there was a way to generate it with a `phoenix.gen` task. I will edit the question to clarify it.

Comment: if it is a has_many relationship, the actual database column will be on the owned entity.  You can generate the owned side of the relationship with a phoenix.gen, but the other side will require code, since it is a "virtual" property.